# place sum of one td data to onother td of next tr by jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".row_val td").each(function() {

     var x  = $(this).children('.val1').text();
     var y = $(this).children('.val2').text();
     $(this).addClass("green")
     var z = x+y;
     $(this).parent().next("tr").("td").(".sum").html() = z;
    // alert(z);
 })
 });
```

how to load sum of one td data to another td of next tr by jquery? please see https://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/y4wmhcw9/11/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var obj = {
    val1: 0,
    val2: 0
  };

  $('.row_val').find('.val1, .val2').each(function() {
    obj[this.className] += +$(this).text() || 0;
  });

  var $sums = $('.rowsubvalue .sum');
  $sums.eq(0).text(obj.val1.toFixed(2));
  $sums.eq(1).text(obj.val2.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="row_val">
    <td>
      <div>Act/Proj</div>
      <div>Rev. Bus./LRP</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="val1">8.5</div>
      <div class="val2">5.6</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="val1">8.5</div>
      <div class="val2">5.6</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="val1">8.5</div>
      <div class="val2">5.6</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="variance_brdr rowsubvalue">
    <td>
      <div>Variance</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="sum"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="sum"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry. this is not my expectation. please see updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/y4wmhcw9/5/    there will be multiple sets tr with similar structure.

Answer (score 0):

What about this: https://jsfiddle.net/y4wmhcw9/8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sumval1 = 0;
    var sumval2 = 0;
    $('.row_val div.val1').each(function() { 
        sumval1 += Number($(this).html());
    });
    $('.row_val div.val2').each(function() { 
        sumval2 += Number($(this).html());
    });

    $('div.sum:eq(0)').html(sumval1);
    $('div.sum:eq(1)').html(sumval2);
 });
```

Comment: it's almost there, just change some lines in your html and this js example and you'll reach the goal